# IIS URL Rewrite + Redirect + does not match the querystring

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting, iis-7.5, iis-10

I need to redirect to another website when the url contains www. and the query-string does not match the specfic value.  I am always getting redirected irrespective of the condition

```
 <rewrite>
                <rules>
                    <rule name="Redirect to Landing Page" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url="(.*)" />
                        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                            <add input="{HTTP_Host}" pattern="www.dev.MyWebpage.com/MCPrivacyNotice" negate="true" />
                        </conditions>
                        <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.myWebPage.com" />
                    </rule>
                </rules>
            </rewrite>
```

Comment: `{HTTP_Host}` means only `www.dev.MyWebpage.com` not full url. Does this make sense to you ?

Comment: thanks for the update but still i am  able to  redirect  irrespective of the condition

                    <rule name="Redirect to Landing Page" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url="(.*)" />
                        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                            <add input="{HTTP_Host}" pattern="www.dev.MyWebpage.com"  />
  <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="MCPrivacyNotice" negate="true" />
                        </conditions>
                        <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.myWebPage.com" />
                    </rule>

Comment: Learn how to edit your question to include new information. Also learn how to debug rules, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you described, so you need to redirect when

- Domain is `www.dev.MyWebpage.com`
- Request uri is `/MCPrivacyNotice`

So I think this may be your answer

```
    <rule name="Redirect to Landing Page" stopProcessing="true"> 
        <match url="(.*)" /> 
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll"> 
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.dev.MyWebpage.com" /> 
                <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/MCPrivacyNotice" negate="true" /> 
            </conditions> 
        <action type="Redirect" url="myWebPage.com" /> 
    </rule>
```

Note that `logicalGrouping="MatchAll"` to match all condition. In your question and your update you used `logicalGrouping="MatchAny"` that means every request from domain `www.dev.MyWebpage.com` will be redirected

One more thing, `/MCPrivacyNotice` is `{REQUEST_URI}` or `PATH_INFO` not `QUERY_STRING` you should choose the right module. Check this for detail https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference

Hope this helps

Comment: How to check Path_info or REQUEST_URI is not empty

Comment: @AbhilashMuttalli you can use regular expression, like this https://forums.iis.net/t/1234744.aspx